# My upper manifold bolts are in too far

Tags: chrysler, stuck-bolt, intake-manifold, pt-cruiser

I pulled a real dunderhead move and I tightened my manifold bolts to 80 foot pounds when it should’ve been 105 inch pounds. The bolts went too far and went passed the threaded inner thread of seat area & passed the threads of the bolt and now I can’t get them out. In other words, there aren’t any threads aligned to let them turn back put. I can’t find a way to push the bolt back up so the threads meet. It’s a very tight space. 07 pt cruiser. ‍♀️

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I'm unclear how under-tightening the bolt caused damage? Or did you tighten to 105 inch-pounds instead of the spec of 80 inch-pounds?

Comment: I tightened to 80 fp instead of 105 ip.

Comment: Ah, oh dear, that is quite a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what's going on, but it seems from your description that you've stripped threads on either the bolt or the hole ... either way, you're in deep doo-doo.

I'll take it you've tried to turn a bolt out and it's just spinning? If so, you'll need to continue trying to get it out. If it is just spinning, something you may be able to do is to force a flat tipped screwdriver under the head of the bolt while you continue to turn it. Once the screwdriver tip is under the bolt head, you can turn the screwdriver and lever it up as you turn which should help you to extract the bolt. At this point, your only hope is to force the bolt out of the hole. If it won't thread out, you'll have to do it another way.

Once you get the bolt out, then you need to assess the damage as to whether it's the bolt or the hole which has stripped. Most likely it's going to be the hole, which is unfortunate. This is because on most engines these days the hole is threaded into aluminum while the bolt is steel. If so, the hole can be fixed with a [heli-coil thread repair](https://www.google.com/search?q=heli-coil+thread+repair), but if you don't know what you're doing, it's best to get a mechanic or machinist to do the repair. It is relatively easy to mess it up.

Comment: I haven’t stripped the threads, the bolt just went in too far passed the threaded coils. The bolt isn’t threaded all the way up the shaft, just the lower 1/3. when I went too far, the threads of the bolt went passed the threads of the inner seat.  I can’t back it out bc the threads of the bolt & the threads of the seat don’t meet. I tried to get a screwdriver  under the head but no go. I don’t want to crack my manifold. I could maybe carve out the outer part of the manifold frame, a part that wouldn’t affect the coils and get something under the head but I’m just not so sure about doing that.

Comment: I need to push the bolt threads back up into the hole to meet the threads of the seat. I just haven’t found a way to do it yet.  And I figured I’m already I’m in deep doo doo. At least 3 of the 5 bolts are correctly torqued.  ‍♀️‍♀️

Comment: @GloriaSchwazenhag - I think you're going to have to provide pictures of exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: I was 100% wrong about the bolt not being fully threaded. I took out another bolt to see and it is threaded all the way. I can’t figure out how to post pictures. I appreciate you trying to help me with this.

Comment: @GloriaSchwazenhag - To post a picture, at the top of the text box where you entered your information, click on the small black icon (sixth from the left next to the curly brackets). Then you can drag and drop into the box, or browse to the image and attach it. You'll need to edit your post. You can't put it into a comment.

Comment: I am so sorry Paul but I don’t see anything like you’re describing. Can you send me a screen shot of what you mean?

Comment: @GloriaSchwazenhag - You'll need to click on "edit" first, which is at the bottom of your post. You *should* be able to see what I'm talking about then ... sorry for neglecting that part of my instruction. Hopefully you can see the little icon you need to click then.

Comment: There is nothing like you explained on my iPad so I went onto my android laptop and there is nothing at all resembling your explanation there either. I went to formatting and is said to press control/g and I got nowhere with that either.  I’ve tried for about 2 hrs over last night and this morn and I don’t know what else to do. I can’t seem to find anyway to do this. I’m sorry for being such a newbie.

Comment: OK, I forced the entire screw and bushing & nut out of the hole (not on purpose). I can see where the inner screw mechanism had locked onto the screw as it’s brass and I forced it and it definitely was not going to come off any other way. So I ground the locking mechanism off (I wrecked the screw & I’m going to replace it). I saw a set on eBay (they’re very hard to find) and I think the locking mechanism of the bushings will be damn near impossible to find so I can salvage enough of the locking mechanism or I can poss. find a nut that’ll fit inside of the hole and I can use a new bolt.

Comment: What do you think? I’m def not taking the other dealio out until I find out if this is going to work but I at least have some relief that pressure is off of part of the manifold.

Comment: @GloriaSchwazenhag - I'm still not understanding exactly what is going on. I haven't dealt with a PT Cruiser engine before and am not getting a visual from what you described. I'd really like to help you, but I'm truly lost on what's going on.

Comment: I can truly appreciate that. So what happened when I overtorqued the bolts is that the inner locknut-it’s located within the bolt hole shaft & bc it’s brass and soft, drew up into the bushing essentially acting like a Molly anchor. I found this out when I pushed the entire screw/bushing/locknut out. That’s why I couldn’t get it out. I could not get the locknut off the bolt shaft bc was cross threaded and cockeyed. I cut it off & ruined the bolt in doing so. I salvaged what I could of the locknut (impossible to find-I contacted a salvage to see if they would get a locknut & ordered new bolts.

Comment: I know exactly what the issue is now. I’ll be more careful when grinding the other locknut off. (Lessons learned). If I could figure out the picture thing, this would all be clear but I get not being able to visualize this. I didn’t even know there was a locknut located in the shaft hole until I saw it. Learning as I go….  Again thank you so much for taking the time with me. If I can ever figure out the pic thing, I’ll post them.

Comment: If the lock nut won’t do-I’m positive it will no longer lock-I will just get a longer bolt and use an external lock nut. Thoughts on this? Well this is my story and I’m stickin to it. At this point. 

Answer (score 0):

I saw a post on another pt cruiser forum and the guy said he was going to cut the head off the bolt and push it thru. You can’t knock the bolt out from the bottom of the upper intake manifold on a pt cruiser bc the lock nut that is located inside of the bolt hole is kind of cone shaped, the hole is narrower at the bottom, wider at the top. It can only come out from the top. I found that out today. I put a metal bar across the left side of the car frame and put a large clamp on the top of the bar. The lower jaw of the clamp I put under the bolt bottom. As I twisted the clamp closed, the bolt, bushing and lock nut popped up enough so i could put a pry bar under it and get it out easily. The bolt wasn’t stripped, it’s cross threaded/crushed onto the lock nut due to being over torqued. The lock nut is soft brass and this can happen too easily. Bolt & locknut are just spinning in the bushing which gives you the impression it’s stripped. Now I’m going to see if I can find some locknuts at a salvage yard. Livin & learnin.

Comment: Got some locknuts at a salvage yard.  Onward & upward.